# XMLReader fails to parse live Xml after 35 seconds

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader, xml-libxml

I am using XmlReader to parse a large xml from a live URL. While parsing I do some extra processing on the xml data i get which takes a bit time and after 30-35 seconds the Reader starts giving bad data. But if i comment-out my time taking code it just works fine and parses everything fine.

i also tested this by removing my code and adding php sleep() and it did the same thing; failed after 30 secs.

i am using hybrid approach to parse xml as suggested on many forums, which is {XMLReader} and then  {$node = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXML());}.

my question is, is there anything like timeout limit or default timeout for XmlReader while reading from a live URl? if so, how to set that? or else this can be?

my xml structure is somthing like this

```
<products>
  <product>
   <id>32454</id>
   <name>products 1</name>
   ...
  </product>
  ...
</products>
```

Comment: The URL you're talking about is missing. And no, there is no such timeout limit.